# Uploading photos in Blender

Tags: import, image

When I'm trying to upload photos in Blender-General using Import in File, its not working. The square outline of the image is coming but not the actual picture itself so i end up with a blank rectangle. Can anybody tell me if there is any way to fix this?

Comment: So what type of image are you importing? Referance image or image as planes are two common import types.

Comment: explain exactly what you are doing. Best with screenshots.